# TableName and PrimaryKey as Table Column

Tags: postgresql

I want to implement a unique identifier for each row record.
The identifier should be unique across all tables.

Therefore I want to use the combination of TableName and PrimaryKey for my identifier.

For example I have the table Contacts:

```
CREATE TABLE Contacts
(
  ContactId                SERIAL,
  FirstName                text,                   
  LastName                 text,
  RowId                    text,         

  PRIMARY KEY (ContactId)
);
```

Example data would be:

```
ContactId: 1
FirstName: John
LastName: Doe
RowId: Contacts1
```

```
ContactId: 1001
FirstName: Jane
LastName: Doe
RowId: Contacts1001
```

Whats the best way of achieve this?

I was thinking about an insert / update trigger that takes care of the RowId column. `TG_TABLE_NAME + ContactId` would work in that case I guess.

However I also want to prevent direct updates of the RowId column.

I was also thinking about using oid and tableoid as identifiers but the documentation says:

> The use of OIDs in user tables is considered deprecated, so most
>   installations should leave this variable disabled

So what do you guys think?

Comment: What's wrong with the `serial` value? That is already unique

Comment: It should be unique across all tables. I edited that.

Comment: Then use a UUID instead. https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-uuid.html

Comment: I will use that, thanks!